# Cake PHP 2.x model validation returns error on field despite data set

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm working with a Cake PHP 2 project and am utilising the model validation and have implemented validation into my [controller](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html#validating-data-from-the-controller)

I've set up my model to contain a `$validate` array with my fields and some basic rules, but when validating the request data with the `validates` method, the validation is failing for some reason.

My model looks ike:

```php
<?php

class MyModelName extends AppModel
{
        /*
        ** Model name
        */
        public $name = 'MyModelName';

        /*
        ** Table prefix
        */
        public $tablePrefix = 'tlp_';

        /*
        ** Table to save data to
        */
        public $useTable = 'some_table';

        /*
        ** Validation
        */
        public $validate = array(
        'age' => array(
                        'required' => array(
                                'rule' => 'required',
                                'message' => 'This field is required'
                        ),
                        'numeric' => array(
                                'rule' => 'numeric',
                                'message' => 'This field can only be numeric'
                        )
                )
    );
}
```

And then I'm validating like this...

```php
$data = [
    'age' => $this->request->data['age'] ?? null,
];

$this->MyModelName->set($this->request->data);

if (!$this->MyModelName->validates()) {
  $json['errors'] = $this->MyModelName->validationErrors;
  echo json_encode($json);
  exit();
}

$hop = $this->MyModelName->save($data);
```

Why would `$this->MyModelName->validates()` always be returning false? I've checked that `age` is in `$this->request->data` and it is, and it's absolutely a numeric value.

`$this->request->data` looks like the following:

```json
{
    "age": 50
}
```

Comment: What _exactly_ (no dummy data please) does the request data contain (try `debug($this->request->data)`)? And what validation error do you receive? Also what's the deal with that unused `$data` variable?

Comment: `$data` is used as part of the save so that I don't need two big data objects (see updated description), and as per my description, the request data contains `age` with the correct value and is set

Comment: That is the actual request data in `$this->request->data` (without any conversion)? It looks like JSON.

Comment: That's how data is built and send to the API, taken directly out of the `body` in Postman, it's a `POST` request

Comment: Ok, but I'm asking for what's in `$this->request->data` for a reason, it can/will be different from the raw body data (the raw data _must_ be converted to an array for the CakePHP internals to be able to work with / see it).